# Windows 10 reading usb data from windows docker container

Tags: windows, docker

I have a program that reads some data from USB, I would be running it as docker container (windows 10) on windows 10, I would like to know if it is possible to read the usb data when I run the program as container (windows container) where base operating system is windows 10.

Regards,
Amit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a key goal of the process is to access hardware devices, it’s best to not run in a Docker container, which intentionally tries to hide details of the underlying hardware from you.  That’s doubly true if you need to use Docker Toolbox, which adds an additional layer of virtual machine.

In addition to USB devices, I’d also avoid Docker if your goals include installing software on the host, reconfiguring or monitoring the host’s network interfaces, or accessing other hardware devices like sound or display configuration.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for the suggestion, we took this in consideration while proposing dockerized solution. Regards, Amit