# Run docker container (using VcXsrv for GUI) on windows 10, But When I use adb to connect android phone, Action interaction is very very slow

Tags: android, docker, adb

Dependency installed:

1. Install docker on my windows 10.
2. Intsll VcXxrv on windows 10.
3. Install adbkit on windows 10 by using npm.
4. install adb tool in docker container.

   apt-get install android-tools-adb
   apt-get install android-tools-fastboot

Run:

1. Connect phone with usb interface on windows 10.
2. Start adbkit on windows 10.

   adbkit usb-device-to-tcp -p $port $serial   # serial is phone no
3. Start adb connect in docker container.

   adb connect host.docker.internal:$port
4. Start my GUI application in container, my application will connect phone using adb. phone UI will show on windows10 by VcXxrv, and you can click phone UI by mouse in windows, then will execute click to phone by adb.

Result:

1. When directly excute click on phone, the UI show on windows10 by VcXxrv very very slow. Need wait 10s and more.
2. When click phone UI by mouse in windows, the click action execute in phone very very slow. eed wait 10s and more.

Comment: Possibly related: [Windows 10 reading usb data from windows docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53745143/295004)

Comment: Thanks for this advice. As for this problem, I have tasken a further test, not VcXxrv tool problem.

I test method as follow:
1. Write a tool for show images by VcXxrv in docker(host is windows10)
2. Judge whether any delay for images show.

Result:
There is almost no any delay for images show, so maby not VcXxrv tool problem.